# Pandas DENSE RANK

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I'm dealing with pandas dataframe and have a frame like this:

```
Year Value  
2012  10
2013  20
2013  25
2014  30
```

I want to make an equialent to DENSE_RANK () over (order by year) function. to make an additional column like this:

```
    Year Value Rank
    2012  10    1
    2013  20    2
    2013  25    2
    2014  30    3
```

How can it be done in pandas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use [`pd.Series.rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html) with `method='dense'`

```
df['Rank'] = df.Year.rank(method='dense').astype(int)

df
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

The fastest solution is [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html):

```
df['Rank'] = pd.factorize(df.Year)[0] + 1
```

**Timings**:

```
#len(df)=40k
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [13]: %timeit df['Rank'] = df.Year.rank(method='dense').astype(int)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.55 ms per loop

In [14]: %timeit df['Rank1'] = df.Year.astype('category').cat.codes + 1
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.22 ms per loop

In [15]: %timeit df['Rank2'] = pd.factorize(df.Year)[0] + 1
1000 loops, best of 3: 737 µs per loop
```

Comment: Note that you will want to use `sort=True` in the call to `factorize`, which will impact your timings as well (in my randomly generated 3M large numerical df, method 1, i.e. using the `rank` method turns out to be the fastest). The reason you assumed it works, is because the array's non-duplicate elements were already sorted.

Comment: Yes, but it depends if data are sort or not. In sample are sorted, so not necessary.

Comment: Indeed, and that's what I said. Because it's sorted, factorize will be faster. In general, data is not sorted and so factorize and rank will return different answers. I added the comment as a warning to future readers, who would blindly take over solutions without checking the conditions under which they're assumed to work.

Comment: @OliverW. - Thank you.

Comment: @piRSquared - Thanks, it hapens. Your solution was upvoted by me ;)

Answer (score 8):

You can convert the year to categoricals and then take their codes (adding one because they are zero indexed and you wanted the initial value to start with one per your example).

```
df['Rank'] = df.Year.astype('category').cat.codes + 1

>>> df
   Year  Value  Rank
0  2012     10     1
1  2013     20     2
2  2013     25     2
3  2014     30     3
```

Answer (score 3):

#### [`Groupby.ngroup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html)

Will sort keys by default so smaller years get labeled lower. Can set `sort=False` to rank groups based on order of occurrence.

```
df['Rank'] = df.groupby('Year', sort=True).ngroup()+1
```

---

#### `np.unique`

Also sorts, so use `return_inverse` to rank the smaller values lowest.

```
df['Rank'] = np.unique(df['Year'], return_inverse=True)[1]+1
```