# SQL to pandas: DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY )

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I am trying to translate the following piece of SQL code to a pandas equivalent

```
SELECT
    t.company,
    t.topic,
    t.statement
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            e.company,
            e.topic,
            e.probability,
            e.distance,
            LOWER(e.statement) AS statement,
            dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY e.company,e.topic ORDER BY e.distance DESC) as rank
        FROM
            esg.group_dist e
    ) t
WHERE
    t.rank = 1
    AND t.topic IN ('green energy')
ORDER BY
    company,
    topic,
    rank
```

I got as far as

```
esg_group_dist['rank'] = esg_group_dist[['company', 'topic', 'probability', 'distance', 'sentence']] \
    .sort_values(by=['distance']) \
    .groupby(['company', 'topic']) \
```

I found the following SO thread that should contain a solution but I can't manage to successfully implement it for my usecase

[Pandas DENSE RANK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39357882/pandas-dense-rank)

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is `groupby.rank`:

```
esg_group_dist['rank'] = (esg_group_dist.groupby(['company', 'topic'])
                             ['disance'].rank(method='dense', ascending=False)
                         )
```

However, looking at your entire query, it looks like you're trying to extract info where `distance` is maximum <del>minimum</del> within each group. You can do so faster with

```
(esg_group_dist[['company', 'topic', 'probability', 'distance', 'sentence']]
     .sort_values('distance')                            # sort values
     .drop_duplicates(['company','topic'], keep='last')  # keep the first rows
     .query('topic=="green energy"')                     # filter topic
)
```

**Note**: to find minimum rows, remove `ascending=False` and `keep='last'`. Also there is `groupby().idxmin/idxmax()` option`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To be fair, I never used SQL so I am not even 100% sure what the goal is. However I would rather say that we are trying to extract info where the distance is minimum instead of maximum, based on 'distance' DESC. Not sure whether I observe this correct though

Comment: @Rens thanks for pointing that out. I always mess up when dealing with `RANK`. Also updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your clear answers. Also love the use of pd.query:  I found myself looking for a good pandas equivalent of R dplyr's  filter function

Comment: @Rens actually, after looking at [a sample](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-dense_rank-function/), `DESC` argument does seem to find the maximum. I guess my SQL is not that strong either :-). So I'm re-updating the answer.

Comment: For later users: The answers do not necessarily produce the same output! For the first, i added a query where I filter on rank==1. It might be possible that there more than 1 record that adheres to this condition. The second possiblity, with drop duplicates, keep='last',  always outputs a single record per group