# Masking dataframe text column to a new column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas dataframe below and I would like to mask ProductId column with a new column. Assign each id to a new numeric value. How can I do that?
Thanks

```
import pandas as pd 
df=pd.DataFrame({'ProductId':['AXX11','CS22','AXX11','FV34','FV34','DF23','CS22'],'Sales': 
[10,34,23,45,23,54,65]})
df
```

Desired outcome below:

```
ProductId   Mask_ProductId   Sales
   AXX1       20              10
   CS22       21              34
   AXX1       20              23
   FV34       8               45
   FV34       8               23
   DF23       12              54
   CS22       21              65
```

Please help thank you

Comment: Answer is duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39357882/pandas-dense-rank?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html):

```
In [96]: df['Mask_ProductId'] = df.ProductId.astype('category').cat.codes

In [97]: df
Out[97]: 
  ProductId  Sales  Mask_ProductId
0     AXX11     10               0
1      CS22     34               1
2     AXX11     23               0
3      FV34     45               3
4      FV34     23               3
5      DF23     54               2
6      CS22     65               1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html)and add [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html):

```
df.insert(1, 'Mask_ProductId', pd.factorize(df['ProductId'])[0])
print (df)
  ProductId  Mask_ProductId  Sales
0     AXX11               0     10
1      CS22               1     34
2     AXX11               0     23
3      FV34               2     45
4      FV34               2     23
5      DF23               3     54
6      CS22               1     65
```